# How do you manage testing error Django projects?

Tags: python, django, api, testing

I need to create a blog post app in which I am stuck in testing all test cases. I need a user which can remain logged in throughout the testing phase so that I can use the same logged in user in blog and post and update_post apis but I am unable to do so

```
def test_login(client, user_data):
    # with unittest.mock.patch('django.contrib.auth.authenticate') as mock_authenticate:
    #     mock_authenticate.return_value = authenticate(
    #     request=client.post(reverse('login'), user_data, format='json'),
    #     backend='django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend'
    # )
      with unittest.mock.patch('django.contrib.auth.authenticate') as mock_authenticate:
        user = CustomUser.objects.create_user(**user_data)
        mock_authenticate.return_value = user
        response = client.post(reverse('login'), user_data, format="json")
        assert response.sstatus_code == 200
```

this is my login api and I want this user to be logged in throughout all apis without using SESSIONS

Answer (score 0):

## app/tests.py

```
from rest_framework.test import APITestCase
from rest_framework import status

class YourTest(APITestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.user = create_user() # Create your own user here.
        self.client.force_authenticate(user=self.user)

    def test_update_post(self):
        # test your apis here.
        # Below lines are just example.
        response = self.client.patch("posts/3", {"name": "jw"})
        assert response.status_code == status.HTTP_200_OK
        assert response.data["name"] == "jw"
```

You can use `force_authenticate` method to get auth on specific user.